# To get a class's variable's latest value, instead of its initial value, in python?

Tags: python, oop

I wanted to get the variable's latest value, instead I get the initial value.
How to get the latest value?
Also, if its due to the string's immutable nature, what's the way around it, while not compromising the usage of string variable.

The following is the simple Python code -

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vr = ''  # initial value (blank/none)

    def input_value(self):
        self.vr = 'Hello'  # latest value (Hello string)

    def return_value(self):
        return self.vr  # want to return the above latest value (i.e, Hello)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Example().input_value()
        cp = Example().return_value()
        print(cp)  # should print 'Hello', instead prints ''
```

Comment: You're creating two different _instances_ (every time you call `Example()` you get a new instance). Assign it to a variable (`ex = Example()`) and then call the methods over that variable. I.E: `ex.input_value()` and `cp = ex.return_value()`

Comment: Please try to avoid breaking your code's indentation when pasting into Stack Overflow. If the four-space-indent style makes that tricky, it's not the only kind of code formatting we support -- you can put three backticks above and below a code section.

Answer (score 0):

Don't discard that initial instance,
the one where you carefully set the value to "hello".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = Example()
    example.input_value()  # mutates the `example.vr` attribute
    cp = example.return_value()  # no idea what `cp` denotes here
    print(cp)  # will print 'Hello'
```

Also, an instance variable (object attribute) is quite different from a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you did, rewritten to highlight the intermediate steps that you probably don't realize are part of the process:

```py
# Example().input_value()
tmp1 = Example()
tmp1.input_value()

# cp = Example().return_value()
tmp2 = Example()
cp = tmp2.return_value()
```

This is what you actually want though:

```py
example = Example()
example.input_value()
cp = example.return_value()
```